# OpenGL(LWJGL) TileMap only displays one tile

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have been recently learning LWJGL since I've been with Java for some time now, and I've learned that since there aren't very many LWJGL tutorials/reference material, I just use search OpenGL tutorials and since I know that LWJGL is like a Java port of OpenGL (I think that's how you'd describe) they'd be basically the exact same, except I always have to tweak it a bit, and I made this code (basically all by myself) and when I run it, it only displays one tile map, but it should display 16 tiles in all! Why is this?

```
package testandothertutorials;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;

public class TileMapTest {

int tilemap[][] = {
        { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 1 }
};
int TILE_SIZE = 32;
int WORLD_SIZE = 4;

Texture stone_texture, dirt_texture;

public TileMapTest() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
        Display.setTitle("Game");
        Display.create();
    } catch(LWJGLException e) {

    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    //Load the stone and dirt textures before the render loop
    try {
        stone_texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("C://Users//Gannon//Desktop//Java//workspace//Test Game//res//stone.png")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        dirt_texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("C://Users//Gannon//Desktop//Java//workspace//Test Game//res//dirt.png")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        drawTiles();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

    Display.destroy();
}

public void drawTiles() {
    for(int x = 0; x < WORLD_SIZE; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < WORLD_SIZE; y++) {
            if(tilemap[x][y] == 0) { //If the selected tile in the tilemap equals 0, set it to the stone texture to draw
                stone_texture.bind();
            } else if(tilemap[x][y] == 1) { //If the selected tile equals 1, set it to the dirt texture to draw
                dirt_texture.bind();
            }

            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                glVertex2f(0, 0);
                glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
                glVertex2f(32, 0);
                glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                glVertex2f(32, 32);
                glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
                glVertex2f(0, 32);
            glEnd();
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new TileMapTest();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try using glpushmatrix() and glpopmatrix(), currently your GL_QUADS are reletive to the last one drawn and so the positioning get far apart the higher x and y do:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(32, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(32, 32);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, 32);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

This will allow each quad to be back in world space coordinates instead of the last drawn quad - I had the same problem once.
Also loading identity should only be done at the start of each new frame and try loading both textures outside the loop and choosing inside, loading for each tile is a real waste on the hard-drive, make use of RAM.

Comment: I implemented what you suggested but it still doesn't work. Updated the code above.

Comment: Have you tried adding glloadidentity() as the first command in the `while(!Display.isCloseRequested())` loop? (beginning of each loop like i said?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs, because your not translating the tiles enough, so you end up rendering all the tiles on top of each other!

Currently your doing `glTranslatef(x, y, 0);` and remember that your tiles have a 32 pixels width and height, but the range that you translate in is only 0 to 4 (since you only render 16 tiles) you need to change your translation.

This is how you should translate.

```
glTranslatef(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, 0);
```

So at the rendering part it ends up looking like this.

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, 0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(32, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(32, 32);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, 32);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```